# arrays additional and average is not showing output in c program but is is asking for the 2 inputs

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int scores[3], sum;
    float avg;
    printf("enter the value for scores\n");
    scanf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",&scores[0],&scores[1],&scores[2]);
    sum=scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2];
    avg=sum/3;
    printf("The sum is :%d\n The avg is :%f\n",sum,avg);
    system("pause");
}
```

When I am running the program then program is asking for the input but it is not showing the output.

Comment: `avg=sum/3;` will produce an integer. Use `avg=sum/3.0` to get a floating point result.

Comment: No it is still not working.

Comment: Your code won't even compile.  Getting an error on the `system("pause")` line.  Also, `main()` needs a return type, i.e. `int main()`

Comment: [This question lacks details.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What input are you giving? How is it failing? Your entry point, main, is also not set up correctly. `int main()` is the standard for most versions of C.

Comment: You mean it is not showing any output at all? What happens if you add a call to `fflush(stdout);` before `system("pause");`?

Comment: You're not using Turbo C++ are you?

Comment: @Tau when a function has no return type the compile assumes `int` but it throws a warning.

Comment: @Muzol even when i corrected that warning, i still got a different error on the other line i mentioned

Comment: @Muzol "a function has no return type the compile assumes int" --> not since C99.  That 19 years old update  obliges an explicit return type.

Comment: @Muzol older versions of the standard allowed that, but not the latest version. Still, if OP is using some ancient C compiler for MS-DOS, the point is moot!

Comment: @Gary Singh "is not showing the output." --> because of the `"\n"` at the end of `"%d\n %d\n %d\n"`.  Use `"%d\n %d\n %d"`.  See [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262107/arrays-additional-and-average-is-not-showing-output-in-c-program-but-is-is-askin#comment91471923_52262107)  What is your result with that?

Comment: @user3121023 I tried that but it is not working.

Comment: @Muzol when I mention int main () and return (0); then it is showing me error [Error] Id returned 1 exit status. I am using Dev C++

Comment: @user3121023 Yes I removed all \n from the string

Comment: Quote: "When I am running the program then program is asking for the input but it is not showing the output" What exactly do mean? If it doesn't print "The sum is …" what happens? What is your exact input?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a few problems

1. `main` needs a return type
2. You should return from `main`
3. `avg=sum/3;` is integer division which means you will not get the result you are expecting
4. The `\n` character in scanf is unnecessary and is going to create problems with your output

This is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int scores[3], sum;
    float avg;
    printf("enter the value for scores\n");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&scores[0],&scores[1],&scores[2]);
    sum=scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2];
    avg=sum/3.0;
    printf("The sum is :%d\n The avg is :%f\n",sum,avg);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I am getting the output now. Thanks

Comment: it would be prudent to point out that 1 and 2 are almost mutually exclusive. If a return type for `main` was mandatory then the return statement would be optional --> user was using C99 . If the return type were not mandatory then the return statement itself is --> user was using something before C99.

Comment: Always, always, always check the value returned by `scanf`

Comment: @Srini `int main` is the only function that is allowed to omit the `return X;` statement: the compiler will supply `return 0;`

Comment: @WeatherVane oh yes, I was talking about the context of main only :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The last `'\n'` in your scanf format is the reason why your program is waiting for the input, scanf will not stop until it receives another non-blank character. So remove the last `'\n'` in your scanf format string like below, and this problem will be gone.
2. `system("pause")`; needs  `#include<stdlib.h>`
3. `avg=sum/3;` will only return the integer part of the result, which may not be the result you except. Try `avg=sum/3.0;`

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int scores[3], sum;
    float avg;
    printf("enter the value for scores\n");
    scanf("%d\n %d\n %d",&scores[0],&scores[1],&scores[2]);
    sum=scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2];
    avg=sum/3.0;
    printf("The sum is :%d\n The avg is :%f\n",sum,avg);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help